# PHP if zero results from first MySQL query, loop another query until until results found

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I've got a problem that's probably pretty basic, but completely puzzling me.

I have a website that pulls nearby zip codes from a location (i.e. if I make my location Detroit, Michigan then I get the zip codes 48201, 48272, 48260, 48226, 48255, 48275, 48267, 48231, 48268, 48278, etc.)  The amount it grabs is variable (Detroit gets 28, Baltimore, MD gets 15).

The website is grabbing nearby locations for deliveries of flowers (In this case, the location is funeral homes).

If there are no funeral homes in the current zip code (i.e. 48201) it should then check neighboring zip codes from `$zipListArray` (48272, etc) until 5 results are found.

I have tried two different bits of code...

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); //This is from the previous query, where it checks the immediate zip code
$i = 0;
while ($num_rows < 5) {
   $result = mysql_query('SELECT funeralh_name, address1, city, state_abbr, zipcode, phone FROM funeral_homes WHERE city != "" AND zipcode = "'.$zipListArray[$i].'" AND state_abbr = "'.$abbr.'"');
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   $i++;
}
```

This code would be an infinite loop on any smaller city or group of cities where there are not 5 neighboring funeral homes.

```
$inc = 0;
if ($num_rows == 0) {
   foreach ($zipListArray as $zip) {
      $result = mysql_query('SELECT funeralh_name, address1, city, state_abbr, zipcode, phone FROM funeral_homes WHERE zipcode = "'.$zip[$inc].'"');
      $total = 0;
      $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      $total += $num_rows;
      if ($total == 5){
         break;
      }
      $inc++;
      }
}
```

This one I couldn't get to work at all.

Comment: Get the lat/long stored in the database and use the [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) to specifically retrieve the 5 nearest locations. No looping required.

Comment: Why not iterate over the list of eligible zip codes instead? You can accumulate all the results in an array, or pick the zip code with the most results, or stop when you get the results you want. In any case, it's at least guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: Please can you post your original query here too so we can see how you are getting the first array of zip codes? It might be that you can do this with one query to your database to save all the looping.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško, I know that I'm not supposed to use `mysql_*` functions, however I'm not the first (or only) developer working on the site, and so I can't recode all the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off doing a `WHERE ... IN` search for all of those possible zipcodes, e.g.

```
$zips = implode(',', $zipListArray);
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE ... AND zipcode IN ($zips)";
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way you only run one query, you get all possible zips, and you can add LIMIT clauses to restrict the results to only 5 rows - or only fetch a max of 5 rows. Either way, you eliminate that for() loop so you don't end up with the infinite loop in case there aren't 5+ nearby flower places in the first place.

Comment: This was what I needed, as I can't change the entire site (I'm not the first, or only, developer working on it).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a terrible idea (querying the database until you have what you got).

Why don't you just improve the query so that it will get the nearest zip code(s) in 1 query (look into the [`abs()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function)?

Or add the coordinates in the database in use the GEO functions of the database engine. Or if that it not avaiable the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

P.S.

Nearest zipcodes are often not nearest location. Use some GEO / maps API for that.

**Update**

*I kinda misread your question, but my initial statement still stands. It is a stupid idea to do multiple queries for this kind of thing*

I only now see you are already having a ziplist to check against. Although I still think this may not be the optimal approach if you really want to go that route you should use [`in()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making multiple queries queries against the database in a loop does not seem like a good approach.  PeeHaa makes some good suggestion in his answers, but if you don't want to worry about geolocation technologies, why not just run a single query like

```
SELECT funeralh_name, address1, city, state_abbr, zipcode, phone
FROM funeral_homes WHERE zipcode IN ('12345', '23456', ...)
ORDER BY zipcode ASC
```

This means you would then have to work with a larger set of data and manually inspect the result set to first find the ones with exact zip code match and then look at alternates. But maybe this is less trouble for you than trying to work with geospatial data.

Alternatively, You could first do a `LIMIT 5` search on just your zip code and if that returns less than 5 records, You could do a second query against all the other zips in the list, limiting the number of results to the number needed to give you 5 total.  This would give a maximum of 2 queries against the database.

Personally I would use Google API or MySQL spatial extensions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) to do this work.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    $zips = implode(', ', $zipListArray);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT funeralh_name, address1, city, state_abbr, zipcode, phone FROM funeral_homes WHERE zipcode IN (' . $zips . ') LIMIT 5');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help give him a maximum of 5 zips in the selected zip code and then look at others zips if there is less than 5.  This would return five records across all the listed zip codes without preference to the one zip here wants to match first.

Comment: This assumed the one zip he wants to check first is already queried, and the `$num_rows` variable has the number of rows in that result. I took the `$num_rows` variable from his second example, and only altered what is inside the `if`.